# Check length of textfield in header file

Tags: templating

Some links in the menu should only be shown if the textfield is not empty. For example:

```
{% if craft.entries.section('aboutus').textField|length == 0 %} style="display: none;" {% endif %}.
```

But `craft.entries.section('aboutus').textField|length` always returns `1`. I also tried `is empty`.

So, how I get the real length of this textfield?

And I have the same problem with a matrix. How can I check if the Matrix field has any blocks?

Comment: "How can I check if the matrix is empty or not?" Does that mean you want to see if your Matrix field has any blocks? Or you want to see if a particular field inside of a Matrix block is empty?

Comment: And want to see if the Matrix field has any blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for a text field:

```
craft.entries.section('aboutus').textField(':empty:')|length
```

To see if a Matrix field has any blocks, it's not as pretty.  There's probably a better way, but it's all I can think of at the moment:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('news') %}

{% set validEntries = [] %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    {% if entry.matrixField|length %}
        {% set validEntries = valid|merge([entry]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

`validEntries` is now an array of entries that have at least one block.

Comment: thanks! But now I have a matrix. How I get the real length here?

Comment: So `textField` is in a Matrix block inside of a Matrix field? Can you update the question with the name of the block and Matrix field?

Comment: No, for the `textField` your version works fine. But now I have the same problem with a Matrix Block. But wait. I will update the question

Comment: And is there a way to check if an `lightswitch Field` is on or not?